# How to assign a struct function pointer to a struct function

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have a struct `Game` with a function pointer called `onBegin`

```cpp
struct Game {
  // ...
  void (*onBegin)(Game&);
  // ...
};
```

What I am attempting to do is allow the user to create their own `onBegin` function, in which they could say

```cpp
void CustomFunc(Game& g) {
  // Do something
}

Game g = Game();
g.onBegin = *CustomFunc;
```

What I am attempting to do is make a function and then set the pointer `onBegin` to point at that default function.

```cpp
struct Game {
public:
  void (*onBegin)(Game&);
private:
  void defualtOnBegin(Game&);
};

// In the constructor
Game::Game() {
  // ...
  this->onBegin = this->defaultOnBegin; // This is what is giving me the error
}
```

I receive the error: `a pointer to a bound function may only be used to call the function` and do not know what is wrong here.

Comment: it's a member function pointer, differs from free functions.

Comment: so if i wanted to achieve what im getting at, i couldnt make the default function apart of the game struct?

Comment: Or make it `static`. It gets the instance by its parameter anyway.

Answer (score 1):

> What I am attempting to do is allow the user to create their own onBegin function...

You could achieve that in different ways, however as you want to go for a function-pointer approach, you might want to utilize `std::function` like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct Game {
    public:
        Game(std::function<void(Game&)> customOnBeginFnc = nullptr) {
            if(customOnBeginFnc) {
                customOnBeginFnc(*this);
            } else {
                defaultOnBegin(*this);
            }
        }

    private:
        void defaultOnBegin(Game&) {
            std::cout << "Default 'onBegin'\n";
        }
};

void customOnBegin(Game&) {
    std::cout << "Custom 'onBegin'\n";
}

int main() {

    {
        std::cout << "Starting a 'default' game...\n";
        Game g;
    }

    {
        std::cout << "Starting a 'customized' game...\n";
        Game g(customOnBegin);
    }
}
```

[Run it here.](https://godbolt.org/z/f5PMdG3dK)

The advantage of that approach would be that you are not limited to free functions but you could also bind a member function to it via a lambda or [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).

Comment: although `std::function` is a valid approach, the code you present doesn't benefit from it.